# Android application 0 process 1 service in Running apps

Tags: android, performance, android-version

Android application is not restarting when application is removed from recent applications. As per my research I came to know that its version issue.

Application is working fine on 4.0 - 4.3. Problem is in 4.4..

How to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: This is android's bug. If you google, you will get many articles on this issue. It has been fixed on Android 4.4.3 if I am not mistaken. You can refer this forum:  [START_STICKY service not restarted after being killed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793)

Comment: I am testing on 4.4.2 version its not working... How can I fix this issue programmatically to work on?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no "clean" fix on this because it is bug from OS. Some people using "dirty" fix like using Alarm Manager to check the status of the service and restart it when necessary but it is not recommended.